# Is it possible Web Application Firewall to return 404 on given url pattern?

Tags: azure, response, web-application-firewall

I'd like to raise HTTP404 Not Found through WAF(Web Application Firewall) when URL has trailing `/`, for example `www.cde.org/aabb/`

I'm following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers), however I can't figure out if/how it can be done.

> You can define a custom response status code and response message when
>   a request is blocked by WAF. The following custom status codes are
>   supported:
>
> 200 OK 403 Forbidden 405 Method not allowed 406 Not acceptable 429 Too
>   many requests

Does that mean that it's impossible to return 404 by WAF?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's impossible by WAF. From [WAF response for blocked requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/frontdoor/waf-front-door-policy-settings#waf-response-for-blocked-requests)

> You can define a custom response status code and response message when
>   a request is blocked by WAF. The following custom status codes are
>   supported:
>
> 200 OK 403 Forbidden 405 Method not allowed 406 Not acceptable 429 Too
>   many requests Custom response status code and response message is a
>   policy level setting. Once it is configured, all blocked requests get
>   the same custom response status and response message.

So you could set it in your backend `web.config` file like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/68137/how-to-configure-a-web-config-file-to-allow-custom-404-handling-while-still-disp).